# Cast an object back to a value type array

Tags: c#, arrays, boxing

I am using reflection to read properties from an object.

If the value I read is a reference type (for example String[]) I can cast this as Object[] array and loop through the strings in the array.

```
    String[] Workers = { "Steve", "Sally", "Jim" };
    Object SomeValue = Workers;
    // Prented that SomeValue is returned from reflection        
    List<Object> SomeList = new List<Object>((Object[])SomeValue);
```

However when the object is an array of value types I can't recast it to an array. I've tried everything. C# for some reason won't recast it as an array of ValueType (thought that would probably work).

```
    Int32[] WorkingHours = { 1, 2, 65, 6 };
    Object SomeValue = WorkingHours;
    // Prented that SomeValue is returned from reflection
    List<Object> SomeList = new List<Object>((ValueType[])SomeValue);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you try `(IEnumerable<object>)SomeValue`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> C# for some reason won't recast it as an array of ValueType (thought that would probably work).

No, it won't work because the *representation* is different.

The reason covariance works for reference type arrays is that the representation of a reference is the same regardless of the type of object it refers to. That's *not* the case if you compare value types and reference types.

For example, consider:

```
byte[] x = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Each element of `x` is *just* a byte. You can't view that array as an `object[]` - each element simply isn't a reference.

However, you can fairly easily convert each element via boxing and create a list that way:

```
List<Object> list = ((IEnumerable) WorkingHours).Cast<Object>().ToList();
```

Comment: Perfect - that's what I was looking for but couldn't quite get it, thanks!